# How to sort object data type index into datetime in pandas?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by

*Index(['Apr-20', 'Apr-21', 'Apr-22', 'Aug-20', 'Aug-21', 'Aug-22', 'Dec-20',
'Dec-21', 'Dec-22', 'Feb-21', 'Feb-22', 'Jan-21', 'Jan-22', 'Jan-23',
'Jul-20', 'Jul-21', 'Jul-22', 'Jun-20', 'Jun-21', 'Jun-22', 'Mar-20',
'Mar-21', 'Mar-22', 'May-20', 'May-21', 'May-22', 'Nov-20', 'Nov-21',
'Nov-22', 'Oct-20', 'Oct-21', 'Oct-22', 'Sep-20', 'Sep-21', 'Sep-22'],
dtype='object', name='months')*

How could I sort this month-year object dtype into the datetime format such as 'MMM-YY' in pandas? Take thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If need only sorting values of index like datetimes use [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) with `key` parameter:

```
df = df.sort_index(key=lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, format='%b-%y'))
```

If need `DatetimeIndex` and then sorting use:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format='%b-%y')
df = df.sort_index()
```

Another idea is create `PeriodIndex`:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format='%b-%y').to_period('m')
df = df.sort_index()
```